# Drawer tableview: dismiss by pulling down

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have built a drawer-like "window" that appears when the user touches a button. The drawer animates from the bottom of the screen and fill the entire screen.

The drawer is actually an `UITableViewController`, hence there is a table in this drawer.

If I've few rows, the user can click the header (which is actually a transparent button) and the drawer will slide down, and it will be dismissed. See the picture below, where the purple color is actually the view controller below the drawer.

[image]

On the other hand, when there are many rows, all the screen is filled up with the rows of the table view; therefore no header is visible. So I'd like to have the following behavior: when scrolled to the top of the tableview, if the user swipe down, the drawer disappear off the bottom of the screen. How would you implement that? Adding a gesture whenever we are at the top of the tableview?

Comment: can someone post a sample code? I tried this "if(scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0)" but it isn't working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UITableView is actually a subview of UIScrollView.  You should be able to implement The UIScrollViewDelegate and implement the "scrollViewDidScroll:" method.  Thus, when your table scrolls, that would get called.  You can detect the content offset and if it is past the top of the table, you could dismiss the view.  You might need to make sure that bounce is enabled on the table so it can go past the top, in case you disabled it.  You may need to make your detection point substantially past the top as well, so it isn't a bad experience for the user.

Comment: can someone post a sample code? I tried this "if(scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0)" but it isn't working

Answer (score 0):

```
extension "Your CollectionView/TableView Controller" : UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0{
            // ......
        }
    }
}
```